# Spring or CDI or EJB3

Tags: spring, jboss, glassfish, ejb, cdi

I am pretty new to the concept of dependency injection and we are currently writing an web app using JSF and maybe Primefaces. We are currently evaluating whether to use Spring or EJB3. I was realy close to choose Spring, but then I heard about CDI. Can you give us some hints, which could be the best for the following situation:

We are currently pretty new to the J2EE world and don't know if we will use Glassfish or JBoss (or can simply stick to Tomcat).

The web app is basically a prototype for an enterprise CRUD application that needs to be able to handle complex business logic. We want to focus on "adaptability", as some requirements are not clear and will be decided about a year later (when we know if we can still use the prototype).

We can't use Hibernate, as we will have to write pretty complex SQL Statements. Currently we made good experiences with the SQL abstraction in Spring.

Maybee I am currently comparing apples and oranges, but there are just too many information's, if you are new to j2ee.  I think that EJB's are the standard defined through JCP, Spring is the standard defined by the market and CDI is a standard that is also defined by the JCP to do what Spring can do. But I am most certainly wrong ;-).

Thx,

iuiz

Comment: Easy question, impossible answer. Certainly your requirements don't rule any of the competitors out of the race. It's fairly easy to google as many flamewars around this subject as you like - and the final decision will be completely up to you and your preferences.

Comment: Thx. But that is a very important point you got there, because at least I know that I am not looking at something completely useless and outdated.

Comment: Ejb and cdi together with a Jboss server has greate flexibility and support

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lincoln Baxter does an excellent job explaining the technical differences in this article:  http://ocpsoft.com/java/spring-to-java-ee-a-migration-guide-cdi-jsf-jpa-jta-ejb/  Long story short:  both Spring and CDI will both be able to provide dependency injection. One is a Java EE standard, the other a commonly known technology.  Glassfish and JBoss both run Spring apps and CDI apps without problem.  As far as not being able to use Hibernate, it's not the case that you cannot use [native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html) within Hibernate.  Save your team a lot of extra dead-simple CRUD code if you can.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this article. It looks quite promising. However the Hibernate thing ist something that I asked some time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769943/java-database-abstraction-for-gwt-or-is-hibernate-a-good-choise and we decided against it.